# Фрагмент и Активити

Tags: java, android, activity

как сделать чтото вроде такой разметки? для этого нужно использовать GridView?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первое что приходит в голову, сделать несколько `GridView`, один под цифры, один под нижнюю часть

Comment: да вот тоже в инете искал, тока GridView нашел, думал может кто знает как лучше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самый верх ставьте

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
               app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
          </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

После добавляйте RelativeLayout в котором поместите:

1. LinearLayout - внутри его расположите GridView для набора цифр, а
   для нижних кнопок используйте RecyclerView если вам нужно скролить
   елементы, а если у вас как на скрине статически 8 елементов, то
   используйте GridView, для нижней панельки поместите LinearLayout.
2. Две View для боковых кнопок.

Comment: ок, попробую, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2):

Использовать `GridView` тут нет строгой необходимости. По мне самое оптимальное `GridLayout`. [Здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/gridlayout.php) всё расписано.